# Are there any non-pathogenic gram-positive bacteria in human gut?

Tags: human-biology, bacteriology, literature, pathogenesis, gut-bacteria

I wish to know if there are any non-pathogenic (not even opportunistic pathogen) gram-positive bacteria in the human gut? Is there any reference that shows there exists a non-pathogenic gram-positive bacterium in the human gut?

I searched the internet but was unable to find anything conclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent *Nature* article, entitled [*A new genomic blueprint of the human gut microbiota*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-0965-1), contains the following Figure:

[image: Phylogeny of reference and uncultured human gut bacterial genomes]

[Fig. 3 Phylogeny of reference and uncultured human gut bacterial genomes]

I don’t know much about bacteria, but, according to their entries in Wikipedia, *Actinobacteria*, and most *Firmicutes* are gram-positive and, as these appear to be present in abundance in the human gut of healthy individuals, one assumes that they are not pathogenic to humans.

Answer (score 0):

Link to wiki: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gut_flora

Found this under Composition -> Intestines: 
The small intestine contains a trace amount of microorganisms due to the proximity and influence of the stomach. Gram-positive cocci and rod-shaped bacteria are the predominant microorganisms found in the small intestine.